# windows azure cloud service

Tags: azure, azure-cloud-services

I used windows azure cloud service.

I added a new web site to the IIS on the production server successfully but my problem when I restart the virtual machine

the site are removed

I change the location of the web site from ( F or E driver to C ) successfully but my problem when I restart the virtual machine the web site return to the location on ( F  or E driver )\

Any help.

Comment: This is not how things are getting done on Cloud Services. If you need to add a new website, associate the project to the WebRole in Visual Studio then re-deploy.

Comment: thanks for answer but what about the second problem :(I change the location of the web site on IIS production or staging virtual machine from ( F or E driver to C ) successfully but my problem when I restart the virtual machine the web site return to the location on ( F or E driver ))

Comment: Because a Cloud Service is managed and provisioned by Azure Fabric Controller. Upon restart (or even regardless of it) it will load the OS image then re-deploy your deployment package. If you need full control over the OS, go with Azure Virtual Machine.

Comment: Thanks again, there is another question why the request are some times site browsing are slowly and some times site browsing are speed. ? I take a Medium VM (2 x 1.6GHz CPU, 3.5GB RAM, 490GB Storage) and there is no huge request for my site ( two users are logged ) .

Comment: It sometimes related to Application-Pool Recycling (by default after configured period of time / number of requests), you can try to disable it or use IIS WarmUp module.

Comment: Thanks again, Is there is any way to force IIS to put my site to C  driver , not on F or E driver

Comment: It's not IIS to blame, it's the Azure AppFabric controller that keeps reverting the role to it's post-deployment state. If you need to use the local file-system, see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee758708.aspx

Answer (score 1):

The behaviour you describe is by design - Web Roles will deploy your site to any number of drive letters (I've seen it change between hosts). Your site is most likely disappearing between reboots because you are moving it to the large "ephemeral" or temporary drive that each Web Role host has.  This is typically larger than the other drives but isn't persistent between reboots.

Your best bet would be to leave the site to be deployed 'as is' unless you have a good reason to need to change - if it's because you need more space for uploaded content, etc, then you might need to consider rewriting those components of your application to write to Blob Storage.  You may even want to look at leveraging the newly announced SMB shares over blob storage for this purpose (http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsazurestorage/archive/2014/05/12/introducing-microsoft-azure-file-service.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You can handle the drive letter in a start up script.

Here is a blog with an example startup script.

[MSDN Blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/lucascan/archive/2011/09/30/using-a-windows-azure-startup-script-to-prevent-your-site-from-being-shutdown.aspx)